# Is grouped case/when priority always first to last case?

Tags: mysql

If you have a parameter that fulfills more than one WHEN in a CASE statement, regardless of query order, is the first THEN which fulfills the condition always delivered and the rest of the comparison disregarded? In other words, is each further WHEN clause in the structure equivalent to an ELSEIF ternary? ***Are there ever exceptions to this depending on random result order?***

```
CREATE TABLE test (non_unique_id INT(11) UNSIGNED, a BOOL, b BOOL);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(1,0,1),(1,1,0),(2,0,1);
SELECT non_unique_id, 
    CASE 
        WHEN MAX(a=1) THEN 'a' 
        WHEN MAX(b=1) THEN 'b' 
    END AS ttype 
FROM test GROUP BY non_unique_id;
```

Returns

```
non_unique_id   ttype
1               a
2               b
```

That's the expected result. My question is whether CASE/WHEN can effectively be used as a way to order a subquery prior to grouping, reliably, under those conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what you are asking, but I sense that you are concerned that perhaps the `MAX` function would encounter e.g. `a=1`, and then report `'a'`, *before* checking the rest of the column to see if perhaps there is an `a=2` somewhere.

As far as I know, the aggregate functions in SQL *must* examine all records for each group (or for the entire table, if `GROUP BY` is not used).  The exception to this might be if the database can use an index, in such a way that not all records needs to be examined.  But even in the case of an index, the database would only avoid examining all records if it could be certain that doing so were not necessary.

Comment: Thanks. Yes - that's basically half the question. If the group function let's say were MIN(a=1) instead of MAX, and it hit a 1, would it terminate and leave out the rest of the column...? The other (maybe more basic) half of the question is whether CASE/WHEN reliably returns in order from left to right...i.e. that a later WHEN that meets some condition will never be encountered if an earlier WHEN meets a different condition.

Comment: @joshstrike `CASE` will short circuit at the _first_ condition which matches.  So, if you happen to have two matching conditions, whichever one appears earlier is the one which would fire .